# Finding the steady state value of v using nodal analysis

Tags: phasor, steady-state

I am currently working on a problem of determing the steady-state value of v using nodal analysis. I understand all the steps up until the step of converting my `j6 / -1-j` to the phasor value that I circled within the red rectangle below.

Could someone give me some insight on what was achieved here and why?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it is just converting the numerator and denominator from complex numbers to magnitude-phase (phasor) notation, which is really short-hand of imaginary exponential.

**Numerator**

`j6` is a vector with no real component (only has imaginary component).  So in phasor terms, the magnitude is `6`, and the angle is `90°` (if it had been negative (`-j6`), the angle would have been `-90°`).  *The angle is measured positive in the anti-clockwise direction, with respect to the positive real axis*.

$$ j6 = 6\angle{90°} $$

**Denominator**

`-1-j` has real and imaginary components equal to `-1`.  So from the origin it looks like an arrow pointing to the bottom-left in the complex plane.  So the angle is `-135°`, and the magnitude is \$(1^2+1^2)^{1/2} = \sqrt{2} \$

$$ -1-j = \sqrt{2} \angle{-135°} $$

---

To answer the question in the comments of why \$-j=\frac{1}{j} \$:

When you divide phasors, the resulting magnitude is the quotient of the magnitudes, and the resulting angle is the difference between the angles.

$$ -j = 1\angle{-90} = \frac{1\angle{0}}{1\angle{90}} = \frac{1}{j} $$

Comment: Thanks @apalopohapa! What I still do not entirely understand is why `-j = 1 / j`. Would you mind explaining this as well?

Comment: `So from the origin it looks like an arrow pointing to the bottom-left in the complex plane. So the angle is -135°` How did you determine this precise angle?

Comment: \$-j=-j\cdot\frac{j}{j}=\frac{-j\cdot j}{j}=\frac{1}{j}\$

Comment: @theGreenCabbage An arrow to the right is 0°.  To the bottom is -90°, to the left is -180° (or 180°).  So the angle between bottom and left is -135°, which is -90°-45°.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It appears I can input the values into my TI-Nspire CX, and it would convert the magnitude to a number I desire. However, I am unable to get the <angle; the value I get is something like `e^01.439*i`.

Comment: In the case of this question, the magnitude is in the right form, but the angle is an exponential number: `e^((-3*i*pi)/4) * 3root(2)`